# Open Graph (facebook share) — ERROR — 'property should be explicitly provided'?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Тестирую пост, как он будет отображаться если его **share**.

Ссылка на тестовый пост [тык](http://www.journalist.today/facebook-share-test/)

Тестировалось тут `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug`

**Тут выбивает ошибки:**

```
   Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
В объекте отсутствует требуемое значение
Объект с URL-адресом "http://www.journalist.today/facebook-share-test/" 
типа "website" недопустим, так как не было предоставлено требуемое свойство "og:title" типа "string".
```

Ссылка на дополнительную проверку в **Отладчик объектов Open Graph**

**По ней выбивает ошибки:**

```
  Errors That Must Be Fixed
Отсутствует требуемое свойство  The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
Notice
Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Share App ID Missing    The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

Пример метаданных на тестовой странице в **head:**

`<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.journalist.today/facebook-share-test/"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/> 
// везде article а в ошибке дает The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
<meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Share Test"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Thanks for sharing!"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.journalist.today/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/платежки-отопление-1.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ЖУРНАЛИСТ"/>`

**Почему не работают метаданные Open Graph?**

Comment: вы нашли причину ошибки? сейчас ваша страница шарится со всеми параметрами

Comment: да, надо установить было доп., плагин для Facebook Open Graph , и настроить его API.